# Trying to limit One2Many field to only records of the same company

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

Basically, I want to put a domain on this field:

```
   line_ids = fields.One2many(
        "hr.payslip.line",
        "slip_id",
        string="Payslip Lines",
        readonly=True,
        domain=[("company_id", "=", self.company_id.id)],
    )
```

But I'm getting:

```
 domain=[("company_id", "=", self.company_id.id)],
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured Odoo have a perfect solution for this, the attribute:  `check_company=True`